# ImportError: No module named six in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: package-management, python, 20.04, pip, ipython

I recently updated to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Ipython was working fine before that. Now when i try to open it, i get an error that (caesar is my usename)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/caesar/.local/bin/ipython", line 6, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/home/caesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/caesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "/home/caesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "/home/caesar/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 57, in <module>
    import six
ImportError: No module named six
```

I have tried to install it using pip, but only pip3 is installed in my system. If i try to install pip, i get an error

```
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

even though all my repositories are up to date. If i install six using pip3 (pip3 somehow is already installed), i get an error saying

```
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.14.0)
```

I need a solution to this, also I need a solution to the problem that i cannot install packages from repositories. I have the universal repositories enabled by default. Please help. :)

EDIT: My utimate aim is to use ipython, any help regarding how to use ipython with python3 would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04, python2 support is removed https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes

Therefore, now you can not install "python-pip" using "apt" and you are getting the error `E: Unable to locate package python-pip`

However, I think you can use [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) to install a specific version of python, then you should be able to use pip in its virtual environment.

Comment: In that case, is it possible to somehow modify ipython to use python 3?

Comment: I don't have much experience with "ipython" but you may try "pip3 install ipython" and if you can switch to "ipython3" then it is available to install with "apt install ipython3".

Answer (score 0):

It was a python 2 error. I installed ipython3 by using `sudo apt update -y` and then doing `sudo apt install -y ipython3` solved it.